# pecl update: pear.php.net is using a unsupported protocol - This should never happen

Tags: php, pecl

I'm trying to do `sudo pecl upgrade` but I'm getting:

```
pear.php.net is using a unsupported protocol - This should never happen.
upgrade failed
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

[This blog post](https://bovitron.com/blogostu/2014/07/06/php-fixing-pear-php-net-is-using-a-unsupported-protocol-this-should-never-happen/) mentions doing `pear upgrade --force xml_util`, which seems to have fixed it.

Comment: to upgrade all use `pear upgrade --force`